# Powershell: How to import csv find a value in a row, list of the column data and over-write some coumns?

Tags: powershell

I think it's easiest to show what I have and what I'm trying to get as an output instead of me trying to verbalize what I'm doing and what I've tried.

Input is a csv that contains:

| Full Name | Color | Access Type | Access ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | Blue | Full_Acccess | jsmith |
| John Smith | Blue | Partial_Access |  |
| John Smith | Red | No_Access |  |
| Bill Bob | Red | Full_Access |  |
| Bill Bob | Pink | Access_1 |  |
| Lisa Smith | Green | Access_2 |  |

I will call this script each time and look for "Full Name".  Then if "Access ID" is empty, I want to populate Access ID (from a variable) and write out the "Output" below to a variable and send that as the body of an email.

So run script, look for "Full Name".  In this case, it will look for and finds "Bill Bob" and since Access ID is empty, it will write "Rob Bob" (a variable value) to "Access ID" but also send email body of output below

OutPut:

> Full Name: Bill Bob
> Color: Red, Pink
> Date: 03-21-2021
> Access_Type: Full_Access, Access_1
> Access ID: Rob Bob

So it's showing a unique Full Name (not all three rows), but also all values of Color and Access Type for "Full Name"

I've got this working using:

```
    Import-CSV |Group-Object -Propert 'Full Name' | Select-Object @{Name = "Full Name"; Expression = {(_.Group.'Full Name' | Select-Object -Unique)}},
      @{Name = "Access Type"; Expression = {($_.Group.'Access Type' | Select-Object -Unique) -join ","}},
      @{Name = "Color"; Expression = {($_.Group.'Color' | Select-Object -Unique)}}, 
      @{Name = "New Name"; Expression = {($_.Group.'New Name' | Select-Object -Unique)}} |
                Where-Object {$_.'Full Name' -eq $PersonName}
```

Where I'm stuck:

Script will be called and imports CSV and searches for "Bill Bob".  Then I want to list all the columns for Bill AND write the new Access_ID value back into the CSV.

Then I call the script again and look for John Smith, and then again for Lisa Smith, etc..

Thanks all!

Comment: Do you want to write back the grouped values, add a new row with the Access ID, or write the Access ID into the existing rows? Is the Access_ID always the same per-user or color?

Comment: I want to write Access ID into the existing row where "Access Type" = Full_Access.   I also want to capture all the grouped values so I can send in an email.  

Basically, two steps.  One, capture grouped values for a "full name" parameter $fullname = "Bill Bob" send all those via an email (so put the grouped values into a variable).  AND then I also want to write the Access ID of "rbob" into the CSV under "Access ID"

Comment: Does anything else use the CSV? Writing back to the csv file may change the formatting slightly, but it wouldn't matter if only powershell is using it. Also, do you always run the script for one specific `$fullname` or can it be multiple?

Comment: I run the script on one specific $fullname because it's only one being passed to the script at a time.  I'm thinking that using an array would solve the issue. $accessType +=$row."Access Type" $props = @{ accessType = $AccessType}  Then I have the values in $AccessType.

Nothing else writes to the CSV. 

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got what you were going for, here's what I would use:

```
Function Get-UserAccess ([string]$fullname,[string]$csvpath){

# Export your output
$csv = Import-CSV $csvpath
$filtered = $csv | Where-Object {$_.'Full Name' -eq $fullname}

$output = [pscustomobject]@{
    'Full Name'  = $fullname
    'Access Type'=($filtered.'Access Type' | Select -Unique) -join ','
    'Color'      =($filtered.'Color'       | Select -Unique) -join ','
    'Access ID'  =($filtered.'Access ID'   | Select -Unique) -join ','
}

# check if Access ID is empty on Full_Access users
if (-not $output.'Access ID' -and 
    ($output.'Access Type' -split ',') -contains 'Full_Access') {
    # Set your AccessID here 
    $AccessID = Read-Host "Enter a new access ID for $fullname"

    # Update the Access ID in the csv:
    $entry = ([Collections.Generic.List[Object]]$csv).findIndex({
    $args[0].'Full Name' -eq $fullname -and 
    $args[0].'Access Type'-eq 'Full_Access'})
    $csv[$entry].'Access ID' = $AccessID
    Write-Host "Updating $csvpath with new access ID for $fullname"
    $csv | Export-Csv $csvpath -Force -NoTypeInformation

    # Return output with Access ID
    $output.'Access ID' = $AccessID
    return $output
} Else { Return $output }
}
```

And some example usage with the data from your question:

```
PS C:\> Get-UserAccess 'Bill Bob' 'C:\temp\temp.csv' | fl
Enter a new access ID for Bill Bob: Rob Bob
Updating C:\temp\temp.csv with new access ID for Bill Bob

Full Name   : Bill Bob
Access Type : Full_Access,Access_1
Color       : Red,Pink
Access ID   : Rob Bob


PS C:\> Get-UserAccess 'John Smith' 'C:\temp\temp.csv' | fl

Full Name   : John Smith
Access Type : Full_Access,Partial_Access,No_Access
Color       : Blue,Red
Access ID   : jsmith,
```